# How to loop thru 3 arrays using only one v-for?

Tags: vue.js

I have 3 arrays in my Vuex State. How to loop thru all of them using ONE v-for? For instance:

```
    export const stepOne = {
  state: {
    textfields: [
      {
        value: "",
        label: "weight",
      },
    ],
    textfieldTire: {
      value: "",
      label: "Tire radius",
    },
    textfieldDocument: [
      {
        value: "",
        label: "Document",
      },
    ],

  },
}
```

Thats how I'm displaying them, but it only shows "textfields" array. How to output data without using multiple v-for?

```
.check-data
    .table(
      v-for='(item, idx) in $store.state.stepOne.textfield'
      :key='idx'
    ) 
      .label
        | {{$store.state.stepOne.textfield[idx].label}}
      .value
        | {{$store.state.stepOne.textfield[idx].value}}
```

Comment: you could created a computed property which get the information from the 3 arrays, format them into one array as you need it, and then you can use a single v-for to loop over the computed property

Comment: @Eli any examples? I have no idea how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A computed property with Array's `concat` method should do the job.

```js
export default {
  /* other properties */
  computed: {
    textfields () {
      const { textfield, textfieldTire, textfieldDocument } = this.$store.state.stepOne

      return textfield.concat(textfieldTire, textfieldDocument)
    }
  }
}
```

Then change the array you iterating through to the one we just created.

```html
.check-data
    .table(
      v-for='(item, idx) in textfields'
      :key='idx'
    ) 
      .label
        | {{item.label}}
      .value
        | {{item.value}}
```

Comment: @YerlanYeszhanov You are welcome. :) You can also accept the answer. BTW I edited code once again changing `textfields[idx]` to `item`.